# AWS 504 Gateway timeout on Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

What we need to consider when lunching a Laravel Application on the AWS server?

I have the local version, with same database and code base, but the page the through 504 error on the online server loading in 1.5 second in my local ENV, with 8GB memory.

We upgraded the AWS server to t3.large, but same result and the page load time is 1 minute and randomly through 504 error.

so what config missed here that my local env is much faster than the AWS server?

Comment: did you check network call while loading the page ? You can check which resource is getting maximum time to load.

Comment: This question would be better asked in [sf].

Answer (score 0):

The Question was about Server but issue is on Laravel, so here I mention if anyone come to this issue as the way I came.

> Very slow query when using Eloquent whereNotIn

In my case I used whereNotIn in my Laravel query, that I give it an array of items to ignore from the query, but looks it make a long query think about a you have 100k items to ignore then all of them added to query.